# Django ordering efficiency with joins - can I force a subquery?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, django-admin

This concerns Django 1.4.6 with a MySQL backend. When doing an ordered query with joins, Django will put the ordering clause at the end of the query. Imagine some models like

```
class MainObject(models.Model):
    pass

class RelatedObject(models.Model):
    main_object = models.ForeignKey(MainObject)
```

If you have a lot of these and try a query such as `RelatedObject.objects.select_related('main_object').order_by('-id') limit 20000` it is, depending on how many joins there are, almost twice as slow as the same query without an ordering: `RelatedObject.objects.select_related('main_object') limit 20000`

This is because the query generated is

```
SELECT app_relatedobject.id, app_relatedobject.main_object_id, app_mainobject.id 
FROM app_relatedobject 
INNER JOIN app_mainobject ON (app_relatedobject.main_object_id = app_mainobject.id) 
ORDER BY app_relatedobject.id DESC
LIMIT 20000
```

which is much slower than the equivalent

```
SELECT tmp.id, tmp.main_object_id, app_mainobject.id 
FROM (
    SELECT app_relatedobject.id, app_relatedobject.main_object_id 
    FROM app_relatedobject 
    ORDER BY app_relatedobject.id DESC
    LIMIT 20000) tmp 
INNER JOIN app_mainobject ON (app_relatedobject.main_object_id = tmp.id)
```

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to achieve in an efficient way? For context, I'm using the django admin system and have a list_display that requires lots of joins across thousands of large records. I can't use raw sql because the rest of the admin system requires a queryset for pagination and filtering.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your SQL query directly. Django allows for [raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) queries out-of-the-box and it does return a QuerySet (specifically a RawQuerySet), which behaves as a normal QuerySet as far as I can tell.